# How to use gmock with xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, mocking, googlemock

I want to use gmock (Google Mock) as mocking framework for a C++ project in XCode. Therefore I have to compile gmock as `gmock.framework`. Unfortunately the project does not come with a dedicated XCode project (gtest has one included).

Creating a Framework project in XCode and building it fails with multiple errors (basically the include paths used in the headers seem to be incorrectly looked up).

So (and sorry for the general question) how to compile gmock as Framework to be able to use it in other XCode Projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get GMock working in Xcode by following these steps:

1. Download this repo somewhere on your machine:

https://github.com/macmade/gmock-xcode

2. Open the included Xcode project, build all the targets by pressing the play button, then close the project.
3. Add the GMock Xcode project to your Xcode project as a subproject (can drag the `GoogleMock.xcodeproj` file to the project browser from Finder).
4. In your testing target under 'Build Phases', add the GoogleMock, gmock, and gtest frameworks under Target Dependencies:

[image]

5. Add the following line to your test files to start using GMock:

   ```
   #include <GoogleMock/GoogleMock.h>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

There is another option using an official repository if the above doesn't work for you.

1) Download an official repository from https://github.com/google/googletest

2) Install Cmake https://cmake.org/download/

3) Optional: Create an environment variable called `GMOCK_HOME` that refers to this
directory. Here’s an example:

```
export GMOCK_HOME=/home/user/googletest/googlemock
```

4) From the root of your Google Mock installation (`$GMOCK_HOME`, henceforth),
do the following:

```
mkdir mybuild
cd mybuild
cmake ..
make
```

Inside of `mybuild` folder you now have `libgmock_main.a` `and libgmock.a` ! Also, note that you have your gtest libs inside of `mybuild/test` if needed.

5) In XCode open your own project and go to target settings -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries and add you gtest and gmock libs.
[image]

6) Add #include "gmock/gmock.h" to your source file and enjoy it!

Comment: This worked for me, I had to add the HEADER SEARCH PATH too, I copied the `include` folder from the `googletest` repo and added its path in the Build Config tab.